# contact page to call in other view as <%= render 'preorder/homepage/contact' %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have scaffold generated preorder and the index page is as

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#detail" aria-controls="detail" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Detail</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#news" aria-controls="news" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">News</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#presskit" aria-controls="presskit" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Press Kit</a></li>
```

contact
  Comment

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="detail">
<%= render 'preorder/homepage/details' %>
<div role="tabpane1" class="tab-pane" id="news">
<%= render 'preorder/homepage/news' %>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="presskit">
<%= render 'preorder/homepage/presskit' %>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="presskit">
<%= render 'preorder/homepage/contact' %>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="comment">
<%= render 'preorder/homepage/comment' %>
</div>
```

Now I have successfully created contact [page form](https://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/)

Now I want to integrate this contact form in as

```
<%= render 'preorder/homepage/contact' %>
```

I added _contact.html.erb at preorder/hompage/ and put code

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
```

```
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :name %>
<%= form.text_field :name %>
</div>
```

and  its giving me error:  First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Please help me to fix this and implement contact page

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: I don't see any question here...

Comment: I want to add contact page in _contact.html.erb in my preorder/homepage

Comment: Odds are @message doesn't exist -- you need to set that in the controller that calls the page rendering

Comment: @message does not exist and if you want to render this partial multiple places I would use it as a local `message` rather than an instance variable `@message` then you can use `<%= render 'preorder/homepage/contact', message: YOUR_MESSAGE_OBJECT_HERE %>` where `message` will be passed as a local variable to the partial. If this is not an object and should just be a standard form then use a string instead e.g. `<%= form_for 'message', url: contact_path do |form| %>`